# Generate month and year from date and store automatically in table

Tags: sql-server-2005

Im working on sql server 2005, i have a column 'Date' of datatype datetime and want to extract month and year separately and store it in two separate columns in the same table as 'Date'. How do i do this and make it happen automatically everytime a new entry is entered where i dont have to manually input month and date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use computed columns or trigger.
I recommend to use computed columns. It's very easy to implement and maintenance.

To get `year` and `month` use `YEAR` and `MONTH` functions

[Computed Columns in SQL Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.90).aspx)

[DateTime functions in SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724(v=sql.90).aspx)